# In Magento 2.3.3 is it possible resize small images

Tags: magento2.3.3, image-resizing

Is it possible in Magento 2.3.3 to resize small images like Gif, PNG, JPG to enlarge with quality?

As I'm doing in view.xml but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

After change ***view.xml*** file run below command after working successfully :

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Happy Coding....